# MYSQL how to select by LONGBLOB

Tags: mysql, blob

I have database where I have column named `content` type of **LONGBLOB**

I want to select every row where longblob (file) is empty, there for `[BLOB - 0 B]`

How to select it ?

Idea:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE content = 0;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE OCTET_LENGTH(content) = 0;
```